# Summing vector pairs efficiently in pytorch

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to calculate the summation of each pair of rows in a matrix. Suppose I have an m x n matrix, say one like

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

and I want to create a matrix of the summations of all pairs of rows. So, for the above matrix, we would want

```
[[5,7,9],
 [8,10,12],
 [11,13,15]]
```

In general, I think the new matrix will be (m choose 2) x n. For the above example in pytorch, I ran

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

y = x[None] + x[:, None]

torch.cat((y[0, 1:3, :], y[1, 2:3, :]))
```

which manually creates the matrix I am looking for. However, I am struggling to think of a way to create the output without manually specifying indices and without using a for-loop. Is there even a way to create such a matrix for an arbitrary matrix without the use of a for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this function:

```
def sum_rows(x): 
   y = x[None] + x[:, None] 
   ind = torch.tril_indices(x.shape[0], x.shape[0], offset=-1)
   return y[ind[0], ind[1]]
```

Because you know you want pairs with the constraints of  `sum_matrix[i,j], where i<j` (but `i>j` would also work), you can just specify that you want the lower/upper triangle indices of your 3D matrix. This still uses a for loop, AFAIK, but should do the job for variable-sized inputs.

Comment: why does this still use a for loop?

Comment: I suspect tril_indices still does, but I'm not sure. It will not be a computationally-expensive one, though.

Comment: @pete It won't be using a `for` loop *per-say* so you shouldn't worry too much about it.